# NetMQ - Communication between Wcf service to Windows Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, communication, netmq

We have a Wcf Service hosting in IIS which receive http requests from many clients (web browser).

The Wcf Service has to do many operations:

- Records data into the database
- Send Emails
- Send SMS
- Check FTP server
- Collect files
- …

So, to relieve our Wcf Service (which not adapted for long running thread work) we have decided to use the Wcf Service to catch only the http request and send a message (with NetMQ) to a windows service in order to do the long work.

To evaluate the architecture, we have written a small demo (see below the code) but we are facing an issue.

Actually, after several http requests send from client browsers to the Wcf Service, the Wcf Service raise the following error:

**"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted”**

I guess, We don’t use well the NetMq library. Is someone can advise us to do it ? 
Thanks in advance.

**The Wcf Service code:**

```
public class DataTrackService : IDataTrackService  
{
    public void PostData(Stream input) 
    { 
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(input, Encoding.UTF8)) 
        { 
            string workload = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
            try 
            { 
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                { 
                    using (NetMQContext ctx = NetMQContext.Create()) 

                    { 
                        using (var sender = ctx.CreatePushSocket()) 

                        { 
                            sender.Bind("tcp://*:5557"); 
                            sender.Send(workload); 
                        } 

                    } 

                }); 
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 
                throw ex; 
            } 
            return; 
    } 
 }
```

The window service code (simulated by console application) :

```
static void Main(string[] args)       
{
       using (NetMQContext ctx = NetMQContext.Create())
       {
           //socket to receive messages on
           using (var receiver = ctx.CreatePullSocket())
           {
               receiver.Connect("tcp://localhost:5557");

               //process tasks forever
               while (true)
               {
                   string workload = receiver.ReceiveString();

                   Console.WriteLine("receiver : " + workload);

               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Best regards,

Cedric

Answer (score 1):

You're binding the address multiple times (`sender.Bind("tcp://*:5557");`) with each and every request that reaches the wcf service.

This might work as long as the requests don't come in in parallel. But when the do, the port is bound multiply which gives you the exception you saw.

So in order to avoid that error you could synchronize the creation and the usage of the `PushSocket`. Maybe use some locking.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch between the binder and the connector.

the static Pull socket should do the binding and the dynamic Pusher should do the connecting.

that way you can connect and disconnect as many times and as many pushers as you like without exceptions all the while your puller will be binded and listening.

you should not- in generla and for this case specifically -  use locking as that will defy the purpose of zmq to be a no bloking async message queue